# Starting an IPython cluster from the notebook with a delay

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Our SGE cluster setup requires there to be a delay between controller and engines starting.  If this delay is not there, some of the servers use "old" `ipcontroller-client.json` files and attempt to connect to previous (and not running) controllers.  This is an NFS "feature", so to remedy, I set `c.IPClusterStart.delay = 30` in the ipcluster_config.py file and things work well.  The controller gets submitted to SGE, has enough time to start and write its json files, and then the engines can start correctly to the newly running controller.  However, I'd like to also be able to start the cluster from the notebook.  Unfortunately, it appears that this timeout is not used, the controller and engines start up at the same time (as seen with `watch qstat`), some of the engines connect (because the pick up the new settings from the json file) and some do not (because of NFS).

I ran an strace on the notebook and saw that it's using `sge_controller` and `sge_engines` scripts (created by the notebook when you press start) to start these processes.

I'm wondering if there's any way to implement a delay here, as well.  It's starting the controller and engines the right way (SGE) so I know it's reading the `ipcluster_config.py`.

I've Googled around and searched this site, with no luck.  Hoping maybe someone can shed some light on the deeper workings of this behavior.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: I found something that seems to work for now, but I still think it should be able to be configured on a per-cluster basis.  In `lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/html/notebook/clustermanager.py`, I changed `delay = CFloat(1., config=True,...)` to `delay = CFloat(30., config=True,...)`.  The cluster now starts as above with a 30 section delay between controller and engines.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is probably too late for the OP, but hopefully it helps someone.

If it is a timeout issue, just set `c.EngineFactory.timeout` and `c.IPEngineApp.wait_for_url_file` to some larger times.

If it is due to failure after the first run, it is probably due to lingering security files, which should be deleted ( `ipcontroller-engine.json` and `ipcontroller-client.json` ) from the relevant iPython profile using `IPython.utils.path.get_security_file` to get the full paths. To automate this and make it somewhat less painful, this deletion step can be tacked on to the beginning of the same profile's `ipcluster_config.py`.

These changes alone were enough for me to get the cluster running with the notebook easily.

If neither of these solve the problem, there are some other thoughts ( http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2011-November/008741.html ).